# Gaussian Probability Density function creation

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process

I am attempting to write the Gaussian probability function and cannot get it right.

From the help for `?pnorm`, the density function is given by:

```
f(x) = 1/(√(2 π) σ) e^-((x - μ)^2/(2 σ^2))
```

From Wikipedia: the function is given by:

[image]

But I cannot get the same result as the built-in function. What am I missing?

```
Pnorm <- function(x, mu, sigma) {
  ( 1 / (sqrt(2 * pi) * sigma) ) * exp( -(x - mu)^2 / (2 * sigma^2) )
}
set.seed(143)
x1 <- rnorm(10)
Pnorm(x1, 0, 1)
[1] 0.11406412 0.32370426 0.14324883 0.38535135 0.38830681 0.39311615 0.09302751
[8] 0.20965959 0.36336998 0.36050112

pnorm(x1, 0, 1)
[1] 0.94322526 0.74102485 0.07617976 0.60383708 0.59191321 0.43190267 0.95603433
[8] 0.87166809 0.33280073 0.67370219
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pnorm` is the CDF; you've written the expression for the density (pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using the wrong function. `dnorm` worked.